# Package Zend Framework but only the components used

Tags: php, zend-framework, package

I'm buidling a new appliction, eventually I'm planning on releasing it onto the Internet for free consumption.

In an effort to reduce the final download size of the package I would like to only bundle the absolute bare ZF components used by my app:

```
Zend
Zend_Application
Zend_Config
Zend_Config_Ini
...
```

I could manually do this - though I'd rather not. Is there a tool around that I can point to my application, it can scan the PHP codebase and create a package with all classes referenced.

I know ZF2 uses composer.json to take care of this - however I'm building on ZF 1.11

Comment: If download size is a concern, I would suggest that you include an install script (I assume you already have one) in which the library could be downloaded and placed in the appropriate location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no tool, to do this job for you. However, I recommend *not* to break the ZF1 into pieces, because it's not that trivial to track down the several dependencies between the components. There is also no benefit: The autoloader takes care, that only the classes were loaded, that are required, thus you only save a small amount of disk space. Thats not worth all the effort it takes. This means you will *definitely* feel no difference wether or not you use ZF1 as a whole, or only partial, unless you find broken dependencies you created yourself.